# Thread safe methods operational costs in Swift

Tags: swift, thread-safety, locking, semaphore

I'm researching operational costs of Lock/Semaphore alternatives in Swift

From the different alternatives one can use (for example DispatchQueue, objc_sync_enter, NSLock), I wasn't able to find specific information related to the operational costs.

I'm looking to implement thread safe operations.

I have used the following syntax:

```
objc_sync_enter(lock)
//thread safe operations
objc_sync_exit(lock)
```

Which method would be the most performant? Any other considerations involved in the different options?

Answer (score 2):

According to Matt Gallagher, OSSpinLock is the fastest on the Mac, but has problems on iOS.  He recommends pthread_mutex_t on both platforms.

His excellent article on the subject, covering all the options including your objc_sync_enter, is [here](https://www.cocoawithlove.com/blog/2016/06/02/threads-and-mutexes.html).